# How to refresh (or force refresh) your browser tabs after internet is restored?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm using Whereby (whereby.com) meetings web app to stay connected to my remote office. I use it on Chrome browser and the PC that it's running on stays on 24/7, so that I could open the link anytime and take a look at the office.

The problem I'm facing is that if internet goes down, the Whereby tab on chrome doesn't crash. Instead, the Whereby app starts giving this notification on top-right, something like "Lost connection, trying to reconnect". And when the internet comes back up, the notification vanishes. But now, if I join the meeting room using Whereby link, it stays stuck on loading after joining, unless I reload the tab on the remote PC.

So, is there a way to automatically reload webpages after internet is restored?

Comment: Perhaps the extension [Auto Refresh Plus | Page Monitor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-refresh-plus-page-mo/hgeljhfekpckiiplhkigfehkdpldcggm?hl=en).